# BigQuery - Join take few hours in 3TB table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables in BQ.

- Table ID: blog
- Table size: 3.07 TB
- Table ID: llog
- Table size: 259.82 GB

Im running the below query and it took few hours(even its not finished, I killed it, so not able to capture the query plan).

```
select bl.row.iddi as bl_iddi,  count(lg.row.id) as count_location_ping
from  
`poc_dataset.blog` bl LEFT OUTER JOIN `poc_dataset.llog`  lg
ON
bl.row.iddi = lg.row.iddi
where bl.row.iddi="124623832432"
group by bl.row.iddi
```

Im not sure how to optimize this. Blog table has trillions of rows.

Comment: please post a job id

Comment: @Pentium10 yulu-poc:US.bquxjob_747f30a1_16efa8ddee3

Comment: Please can you post query plan execution picture? see: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation > Viewing information with the classic BigQuery web UI. This should shed some light on where the query is being held up.

Comment: @ParthMehta I killed the job. So there is no info in the explain plan (no slots info, no number of files and etc)

Comment: Did you try without the group by at the end? I think this is the pain point here.

Comment: If you already know the `row.iddi`, why are you joining?  Just query `llog` directly.

Comment: I do agree with rtenha's comment, just count the rows in the llog table where lg.row.iddi = 124623832432

Answer (score 0):

Unless some extra details are missing in your question - below should give you expected result

```
#standardSQL
SELECT row.iddi AS iddi,  COUNT(row.id) AS count_location_ping
FROM `poc_dataset.llog`
WHERE row.iddi= '124623832432'
GROUP BY row.iddi
```